# 1-dimensional and n-dimensional torus

Tags: general-topology

> Question:
>
> Define the n-dimensional torus $T^{n}$ for n $\in \mathbb{Z}$.
> What is $T^{1}$ better known as?

Recalling the definition of a 2-dimensional torus,
the n-dimensional torus $T^{n}$ is the quotient space obtained from $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ by the relation x~y IFF $x-y \in \mathbb{Z}^{n}$.
A 2-dimensional torus, is formed by *gluing* $\left [ 0,1 \right ] \times \left [ 0,1 \right ]$.
A 1-dimensional torus certainly requires only $\left [ 0,1 \right ]$.
Is it a circle?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1-dimensional torus T^1=R/Z

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By [common definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus), we have: 
$$T^n = \underbrace{S^1 \times S^1 \times \dots \times S^1}_{n-\text{times}}$$
So, 
$$T^1 = S^1,$$ the one-sphere; you are correct.